# I am having error with ajax toolscript manager on shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, ajax, toolkitscriptmanager

My page is workin fine on other hosting but i am getting error on shared hosting.

error:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager  ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding a little line of code in web.config solved my problem

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web> 
   <trust level="Full" /> 
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```